# HANA demo database with data sample

Tags: hana

I Need to do a demo with Power BI and SAP HANA database. But I don't know how to find sample data for my HANA database. Does anyone know if there is a platform with sample data for databases?

Thanks & Regards,

Answer (score 1):

By installing the demo/education apps of the SHINE package you get just such a demo schema with data.

The SHINE package can be downloaded from SAP Software Center and also be found on GitHub https://github.com/SAP/hana-shine.